# Adding Value in variable (If statement)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm trying to figure this out, I have a counting app and want it to increase by 45. Assume the user clicks + 5 times, they can only subtract it -5 for it to equal 0.

Here is my if statement but it doesn't work, it goes into the negatives. 
Can anyone help? It's not coming to me. It's the `(if count >= 0)`

```
-(IBAction)upButton45:(id)sender {
    xCount1 +=1;
    countNumber45 +=45;
    x45Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"45x%i", xCount1];
    totalWeight += 45;
    TotalWeightLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d LBS", totalWeight];
}


-(IBAction)downButton45:(id)sender {
    xCount1 -= 1;
    countNumber45 -= 45;
    x45Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"45x%i", xCount1];
    if (countNumber45 <= 0) {
        countNumber45 = 0;
        xCount1 = 0;

        x45Label.text = @"";
    }
    if (xCount1 >= 0) {
        totalWeight -= 45;
        TotalWeightLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d LBS", totalWeight];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)upButton45:(id)sender 
{
    if(xCount + 1 <= 45) //Your max allowed tap
    {   
        xCount1 +=1;
        countNumber45 +=45;
        x45Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"45x%i", xCount1];
        totalWeight += 45;
        TotalWeightLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d LBS", totalWeight];
    }

}


-(IBAction)downButton45:(id)sender
{
    if(xCount - 1 >= 0)
    {
        xCount1 -= 1;
        countNumber45 -= 45;
        x45Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"45x%i", xCount1];
        totalWeight -= 45;
        TotalWeightLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d LBS", totalWeight];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I added in an extra line for the down button and it worked, although your code for up button didn't work! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)upButton45:(id)sender
{
    //Assuming that the lable always hold value and have "0" as start value, and number is at first position
    NSArray *stringList = [TotalWeightLabel.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    int currentValue =  [(NSString *)stringList[0] intValue];

    currentValue = currentValue + 45;
    TotalWeightLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d LBS", currentValue];
}


-(IBAction)downButton45:(id)sender
{
    //Assuming that the lable always hold a int value and number is at first position
    NSArray *stringList = [TotalWeightLabel.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    int currentValue =  [(NSString *)stringList[0] intValue];

    if (currentValue != 0) {
         currentValue = currentValue - 45;
    }
    TotalWeightLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d LBS", currentValue];
}
```